# Iterating over list

Tags: python

I am currently doing a small pet project and i have come this far, currently my code accepts the string, changes the string into the respective cipher and displays it but its displaying the whole iterated string. What i am doing wrong ? i want only the translated string.

**Code**

```
def encrypt_letter(letter):
    cipher = {'a': 'n', 'b': 'o', 'c': 'p', 'd': 'q',
              'e': 'r', 'f': 's', 'g': 't', 'h': 'u',
              'i': 'v', 'j': 'w', 'k': 'x', 'l': 'y',
              'm': 'z', 'n': 'a', 'o': 'b', 'p': 'c',
              'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'g',
              'u': 'h', 'v': 'i', 'w': 'j', 'x': 'k',
              'y': 'l', 'z': 'm'}
    lowercase_letter = letter.lower()
    return cipher[lowercase_letter]

def encrypt(string):
    result = []
    letters = list(string)
    for letter in letters:
        encrypted_letter = encrypt_letter(letter)
        result.append(encrypted_letter)
        print "".join(result)

e = encrypt("hello")
print e
```

**Output**

```
u
ur
ury
uryy
uryyb
None
```

**Expected output**

```
'uryyb'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One minor change will do! What you want is to `return` the string.

```
def encrypt(string):
    result = []
    letters = list(string)
    for letter in letters:
        encrypted_letter = encrypt_letter(letter)
        result.append(encrypted_letter)
    return "".join(result) # change to return

e = encrypt("hello")
print e # will give you expected output
```

In fact, you can write shorter code with this:

```
def encrypt(string):
    cipher = {'a': 'n', 'b': 'o', 'c': 'p', 'd': 'q',
              'e': 'r', 'f': 's', 'g': 't', 'h': 'u',
              'i': 'v', 'j': 'w', 'k': 'x', 'l': 'y',
              'm': 'z', 'n': 'a', 'o': 'b', 'p': 'c',
              'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'g',
              'u': 'h', 'v': 'i', 'w': 'j', 'x': 'k',
              'y': 'l', 'z': 'm'}
    return ''.join(cipher[s] for s in string.lower())
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing out the list with each iteration of the for-loop.  You need to do two things to fix the problem:

1. Dedent `print "".join(result)` one level.
2. In that line, change `print` to [`return`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

Here is the full code:

```
def encrypt_letter(letter):
    cipher = {'a': 'n', 'b': 'o', 'c': 'p', 'd': 'q',
              'e': 'r', 'f': 's', 'g': 't', 'h': 'u',
              'i': 'v', 'j': 'w', 'k': 'x', 'l': 'y',
              'm': 'z', 'n': 'a', 'o': 'b', 'p': 'c',
              'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'g',
              'u': 'h', 'v': 'i', 'w': 'j', 'x': 'k',
              'y': 'l', 'z': 'm'}
    lowercase_letter = letter.lower()
    return cipher[lowercase_letter]

def encrypt(string):
    result = []
    letters = list(string)
    for letter in letters:
        encrypted_letter = encrypt_letter(letter)
        result.append(encrypted_letter)
    ######################
    return "".join(result)
    ######################

e = encrypt("hello")
print e
```

Output:

```
uryyb
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` is inside the `for` loop; dedent it one level, i.e.

```
    result.append(encrypted_letter)
print "".join(result)
```

This will prevent the repeated printing out through the loop. Also, nothing gets `return`ed from your function, add:

```
return result
```

at the end (either additional to or replacing the `print`) to send your output to `e`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
    print "".join(result)
```

falls in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd return a string from `encrypt`, not print one.

```
def encrypt(string):
    result = ""
    for letter in list(string):
        result += encrypt_letter(letter)
    return result

print(encrypt("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt(string):
  return ''.join([encrypt_letter(letter) for letter in string])
```

output:

```
uryyb
```